# MATLAB function to find the argument of a discrete time complex signal

Tags: matlab

I have a MATLAB question. How can I calculate and subsequently plot the argument of

$$x(n) = e^{(0.1 + 0.3j)n}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
n=1:3;
x=exp((0.1+i*0.3)*n);
p=angle(x)
plot(p)
```